# Array.map item to a state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, state

How do I get the values of **array.map** outside of it?

For example:

```
array.map(index, item) => { return ( <Text>{item.ID}</Text> ) }
```

Ouside of it I have something like:

```
<Button onPress={() => this.editItem(CURRENT_ITEM_ID)}></Button>
```

Where CURRENT_ITEM_ID is the current item on a Card, for example.

Like Tinder I have an array of Cards to Swipe, that I'm *mapping*, but the Like button is not part of the Card. This way I'm not moving the Like button with the Card, instead it is static, I'm just moving the content of the card. So I need a way to access the current *item* from outside of the map. The Card has Text and ID. The component below have a Button that I need to click passing the *item.ID* of the current Card.

Is there a way to set this item to a state?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you setting the current item?

Comment: How are you displaying the correct card when you swipe? You must be storing this somewhere already.

Comment: CURRENT_ITEM_ID is the item from the map. I need to access it from outside of the map.

Comment: But you want to access the components generated in the map function (in this case you need to store the result from map in a variable and access that) or the underlying item (in which case you would use array.find)?

Comment: Curious.... is there ever more than one Button or Card on the screen at any given time?

Comment: @djfdev a Card (mapped) and a view with 3 buttons trying to access the map items.

Comment: @Thiatt yes, but inside I don't know how to set something that is not a component

Comment: can't you wrap your card swipe+button in a top component that stores the id of the current card and pass it down as a prop?

Comment: @Thiatt, not sure if I know how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean (mapped)? I don't understand why you're mapping over this array in render, when you're only showing one card at a time. Ideally, you have the array as a prop, and in state you can store the currentItemIndex. Then you can "swipe" the cards left or right to change the currentItemIndex, and re-render the next/previous card and associated button while passing in that index.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a state property that holds the id of the card that is showing, and then when the button is clicked, you grab that state and do something with it.  Here is an example with onClicks and divs.

```
const arr = ['card1', 'card2', 'card3', 'card4'];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(index) {
    this.setState({ visibleCard: index });
  }
  handleButtonClick() {
    console.log('this.state.visibleCard', this.state.visibleCard);
    console.log('visibleCard', arr[this.state.visibleCard]);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {arr.map((card, i) => <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}>{card}</div>)}
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>test</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The basic idea is that you tie the index to the card.  A handler then sets that state to visible(not sure what this would be in your case since it seems like a mobile app).  Then in your button, you use the state to grab the visible card and pass the data to whatever other function you need.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is bind the event in the map function.

```
array.map( (item, key) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Text>{item.ID}</Text>
            <button onClick={this.editItem.bind(this, item.ID)}>Edit</button> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Not sure what your HTML looks like, but you need to bind the function params in the map.

Comment: I need this button to be outside of the map. The way you show me works, but it must be like Tinder. You move the content, but the actions are static. In my case, the Card has the item.ID, but my button can't access the item.